# How to to push the data to an array by delay 200ms in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I use tcp socket to receieve the data from server（about 100 times in one second） , When I receieve the data ,I want to push it into an array by delay 200ms, How to do?

Comment: check these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift

Comment: http://www.whatx.net/questions/24170282/swift-performselector-withobject-afterdelay.look at these metods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dispatch_after to run a closure after a specified amount of time. You just need to determine which of the queues your closure should run on, documentation on the queues and their purpose here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_global_queue

For this example I'll use QOS_CLASS_UTILITY which is intended for long running background tasks.

```
let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.value)
let delayInMilliseconds = 200
let delay = Int64(delayInMilliseconds * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC))
let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay)
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(qos,0)) {
    //code to push data into array 
}
```